# ResultMap mybatis not working

Tags: xml, mybatis

I have this simple mapper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0 Powerhouse//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-Powerhouse-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="nl.powerhouse.data.domain.CountryMapper">
<resultMap id="countryDsoMap" type="nl.powerhouse.domain.common.types.algemeen.Land">
    <id column="land_id"/>
    <association property="landId" columnPrefix="land_" column="id"/>
    <association property="landcode" columnPrefix="land_" column="landcode"/>
    <association property="landnaam" columnPrefix="land_" column="landnaam"/>
    <association property="landnummer" columnPrefix="land_" column="landnummer"/>
    <association property="handelsland" columnPrefix="land_" column="handelsland"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="findCountryByCode" resultMap="countryDsoMap">
    select <includeColumns tableAlias="land" columnPrefix="land_" refid="nl.powerhouse.data.dao.algemeen.LandMapper.Base_Column_List"/>
    from alg_t_land land
    where landcode = #{countryCode}
</select>
```

And this Land.java class

```
public final class Land implements Serializable {

    private LandId landId;
    private String landcode;
    private String landnaam;
    private String landnummer;
    private boolean handelsland;

    public Land() {
        // default constructor for mybatis
    }
    // getters...
}
```

But, when I am trying to use it, I get the following error:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is    org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### The error may exist in nl/powerhouse/data/domain/CountryMapper.xml
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
...
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:75)
```

I know that the query is working, the problem is with the resultMap, any hint?

Comment: Your id: `<id column="land_id"/>`  doesn't have attribute `property`. I guess you need to put `<id column="land_id" property="landId"/>` or how the property id its called in `Land`

Comment: I tried but did not work neither

Comment: Otherwise, why are you using tag `association`? Replace <association> for <result>. Example:  `<result property="handelsland" columnPrefix="land_" column="handelsland"/>`

Comment: With result works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `<association>` tag instead of `<result>` which is the tag used to JavaBean properties as you can see in the documentation of [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps):

> ResultMap
>
> **result** – a normal result injected into a field or JavaBean property
>
> **association** – a complex type association; many results will roll up
>   into this

Definitively, your mappings are not complex type association so instead of use `<association>` you must use `<result>`.

Your result map would be:

```
<resultMap id="countryDsoMap" type="nl.powerhouse.domain.common.types.algemeen.Land">
    <id column="land_id"/>
    <result property="landId" columnPrefix="land_" column="id"/>
    <result property="landcode" columnPrefix="land_" column="landcode"/>
    <result property="landnaam" columnPrefix="land_" column="landnaam"/>
    <result property="landnummer" columnPrefix="land_" column="landnummer"/>
    <result property="handelsland" columnPrefix="land_" column="handelsland"/>
</resultMap>
```